# Display Times available based on the Date in a form (looking for solution with useReducer)

Tags: reactjs, forms

Honestly i cant wrap my Head around how to create and write the Function of updateTimes which will update the Times option in my Form based on the selected date. Those are my instruction:

Step 2: Update BookingForm to display available times based on the selected date
The next step is to prepare the available times to be updated based on the date the user has selected. To do this, you will change the availableTimes state to a reducer.

In the Main component, create a function named updateTimes which will handle the state change. This function will change the availableTimes based on the selected date. For now, the function can return the same available times regardless of the date.

Next, create a function called initializeTimes which will create the initial state for the availableTimes.

Then, change availableTimes to a reducer using the useReducer function and provide the two previous functions as parameters.

Update the BookingForm component to dispatch the state change when the date form field is changed.

This is the Code ive been able to get to until now:

```
const formReducer= (state, event) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        [event.name]: event.value
    }
}
```

```
function Bookingform(props){
    const [formData, setFormData] = useReducer(formReducer, {});
    const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState();
    
    const times = [
        {value: "17:00", text: "17:00" },
        {value: "18:00", text: "18:00" },
        {value: "19:00", text: "19:00" },
        {value: "20:00", text: "20:00" },
        {value: "21:00", text: "21:00" },
        {value: "22:00", text: "22:00" },
      ]
   

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setSubmitting(true);
        props.onSubmit(formData);
        setTimeout (() => {
            setSubmitting(false);
        }, 3000)
    };

    const handleChange = event => {
        const isCheckbox = event.target.type === "checkbox";
        setFormData({
            name: event.target.name,
            value: event.target.value,
            value: isCheckbox ? event.target.checked : event.target.value,
            
        });
    }


    return (
        <div className="Wrapper">
            <h1>Reserve a Table</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <fieldset>
                    <field name="field" value={field}>
                    <label>
                        <p>Time</p>
                        <select name="Time" onChange={handleChange}>
                            {times.map((option, index) => (
                            <option key={index} value={option.value}>
                            {option.text}
                            </option>
                            ))}

                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <p>Date</p>
                        <input type="date" name="Date" onChange={handleChange}/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <p>Guests</p>
                        <input type="number" name="Count" min="1" max="9" onChange={handleChange} step="1"/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                    <p>Choose Occasion</p>
                        <select name="Occasion" onChange={handleChange}>
                            <option>Anniversary</option>
                            <option>Birthday</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                 </field>
                </fieldset>

            </form>
        </div>
    )

}
```

im quite stuck at this point and cant wrap my Head around the Solution, a explanation for my Problem would be great ! thanks in advance.

I was trying to write a function which is able to Update the Times with the Selected options inside Date, but anytime im trying to write it my whole Site actually breaks. I dont get to much smarter from reading the Docs tho... i do understand pretty much how the useReducer Works but i cant find a way to implement it in this Situation.